# Possible to obtain association bonus from deleted account?

Tags: bug, reputation, association-bonus

I was a little confused earlier today at how a user with only 4 accounts got the [association bonus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16952718/callum-morrisson?tab=reputation). Their SO account has a few posts, but their other accounts, on Stack Exchange, Super User, and Mathematics all have 101 reputation, all from the association bonus.

It appears, however, that the user deleted their account (I assume just the SO and perhaps SE accounts) and then recreated it (they [have admitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411627/why-are-privileged-users-allowed-to-misuse-power#comment868638_411627) this in a deleted question), however, as the user was eligible for the association bonus before they have received it again.

Is this intended behaviour? I would personally suggest it shouldn't be, especially if, for example, the restriction the user had was a question/answer ban; if their old account received such a ban then they by definition *don't* understand how the sites work and so shouldn't be getting the association bonus, no?

Comment: Could it be a hidden community providing the association bonus? I have no clue, never really tested that

Comment: at MSE: [Association Bonus not removed upon account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191415/165773)